# What happened at New Jerusalem?

Tags: heavy-gear

I've been reading the Heavy Gear 3rd Edition Earth Companion.  They talk about the NEC's 7th Fleet disappearing while on mission to occupy New Jerusalem.  In the Earth Companion there is no indicator what happened to the fleet.  Is this revealed and if so what happened?  Also what book(s) is that discussed?

Answer (score 1):

I don't have access to my Heavy Gear library but I believe there is mention of sparse radio chatter and battle mentioned in either the Atlantis or Utopia source books from 2nd edition.

Comment: I'd love if you can find the actual books.

Comment: Unfortunately, I will not be able to retrieve my library for about four more months.  I will ask around and see what I can find.

Comment: Since I will not gain access to my library for quite some time and there appear to be few Heavy Gear experts so far, I'd recommend re-asking your question to: http://dp9forum.com/